# Parametric equations, Exponential Function.

Tags: calculus, parametric

Consider the curve defined by the parametric equations $x=t^2 +t-1$ and $y=te^{2t}$

i) Show that $dy/dx =e^{2t}$

ii) Hence show that the tangent to the curve at the point on the curve where $t= -1$ passes through the origin.

I'm sorry to bug you guys, but I'm clueless and would help me if someone could help me, so I get questions that are similar to this. Thanks!

Comment: for the first part, use the fact that dy/dx = (dy/dt)/(dx/dt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{2t}+2te^{2t}=e^{2t}(1+2t)$$

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=2t+1 $$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

At $t=-1,x=-1, y=-e^{-2}$

So, the equation of the tangent  will be $$\frac{y-(-e^{-2})}{x-(-1)}=\frac{dy}{dx}_{\text{(at }t=-1)}=e^{-2}\implies y=x\cdot e^{-2}$$ which clearly passes through the origin $(0,0)$

Comment: @RogerShan, my pleasure.

Comment: Excuse me, I would like to ask how do you mark a question to be answered? sorry Im new with this site.

Comment: hahaha dw got it